# How does K-Means work?

Tags: algorithm, k-means

I'm lost and confused on how K-Means work. What I know so far is

1. plot n points, say 7 points
2. randomly choose k points, say 3 points which will serve as centroids
3. centroids will be the type of classes so we have 3 classes
4. pick a point to classify its class
5. nearest class from the chosen 3 will classify the point picked

I have already implemented getting a text file which contains the points. Once I select a file, the points will be plotted. And now I stopped there.

Here's what I want to know:

1.I want to know the next things that I should do after plotting the points because I'm not sure of the algorithm that I stated above.

2.And I want to know how the iteration works, iteration for getting the final classes of each of the point. I'm confused because I don't know how the picked point change class if it gets the class from the nearest point with class

Any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: Are you following [this](http://nlp.stanford.edu/IR-book/html/htmledition/k-means-1.html)?

Comment: What exactly is this to do with java?

Comment: @SotiriosDelimanolis I have read a lot of articles about it and I even asked someone to explain this to me but I still don't understand. Good site btw

Comment: @mikea I am making a java program about k-means.

Answer (score 12):

The input to K-Means is a set of points (observations), and an integer K. The goal is to partition the input points into K distinct sets (clusters).

The first step is to initialize the algorithm by choosing K initial cluster centroid locations. This is typically done by randomly choosing K points from the input set. With these initial K centroids, the algorithm proceeds by repeating the following two main steps:

1) **Cluster Assignment** - Here, each observation (e.g., each point in the data set) is assigned to a cluster centroid such that the WCSS objective function is minimized. This can often be translated to assigning each observation to the closest cluster centroid (which coincidentally minimizes WCSS for many distance metrics), though for some distance metrics and spaces this need not be the case.
2) **Update Centroids** - After all of the input observations have been assigned to a cluster centroid, each centroid is re-computed. For each cluster, the new centroid is computed by averaging the observations that were assigned to it (e.g., computing the 'mean' of the observations).

These steps are repeated until the algorithm "converges". There are several ways to detect convergence. The most typical way is to run until none of the observations change cluster membership. As an additional tip, if you compute the WCSS (explained below) for each iteration, you should see it decrease (e.g., the error should become smaller as the algorithm runs). If not, you're implementation probably has a bug.

It's also important to understand that K-Means is notorious for getting stuck in local minima. This means that the final result may not be the best result. To overcome this, K-Means is often run many times with different starting points (initial centroids), and the run with the lowest error is chosen.

Within-cluster sum of squares (WCSS) is used to measure the error (it's explained on Wikipedia: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/K-means_clustering). WCSS is computed as

```
totalError = 0;
foreach(Point p in inputData)
{
    // compute p's error
    pError = someDistanceFunc(p, p_centroid)^2 
    totalError += pError;
}
```

Essentially, for each point you compute an error measure based on how close it is to it's centroid. All of these errors are added up to compute the total error.

There is a lot of K-Means information available on the internet. For a more in-depth description I recommend Andrew Ng's Coursera lectures:
http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Ao2vnhelKhI

Comment: That's a very vague description of the algorithm - I doubt it would be particularly helpful.

Comment: @SotiriosDelimanolis I added a description of how the error is computed.

Comment: @Dukeling I've added some more details

Comment: **Stop computing distances**. Stick to squared deviations. That is what k-means is doing, it's not using euclidean distance and squaring the result. It's **minimizing variance**.

Comment: @Anony-Mousse What use of distance are you referring to specifically? I don't think it's unreasonable to explain K-Means in terms of assigning observations to cluster centroids based on *distances*, etc. In fact, this is what Andrew Ng does in his Coursera course - http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Ao2vnhelKhI. I understand that the actual objective function is to minimize WCSS, but to do that in Euclidean space you compute distances, no? Help me understand what you mean please.

Comment: I know that this is popular, but it leads to a lot of failed attempts to use k-means with other distances. There is nothing wrong with assigning using least-sum-of-squares. Sum of squares is simpler than Euclidean distance (by not having a square root).

Comment: Similarly, lots of books give the Lloyd algorithm, and attribute it to MacQueen... it's not entirely wrong, but also not entirely correct; in particular, people using such material tend to believe there is only a single algorithm for k-means.

Comment: @mattnedrich hello mr.matt, i'm still confused. say k centroids are randomly chosen everytime it iterates. don't you think it will have infinite iterations?

Comment: @ThisGuy K centroids are chosen for each execution of K-Means. That is, you choose K initial centroids, run K-Means (iterate until it converges) and get a result (clustering and error). You can then re-run it all over again with K different initial centroids and potentially get a new clustering and error. This is because where it converges to is sensitive to the starting centroid locations (i.e., running it once may not yield the best result). That's why if you run it several times with different initial centroids you can reduce the likelihood that you didn't find the best result.

Comment: @Anony-Mousse Thanks for the explanation, I also see that the description on Wikipedia explicitly calls this out "**The algorithm is often presented as assigning objects to the nearest cluster by distance. This is slightly inaccurate: the algorithm aims at minimizing the WCSS objective**" I'll keep this in mind, and update my answer to reflect this.